# How to fetch and display selected value into <select2> tag in my Edit Form using ajax (codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I create one form which includes select2 control.and i have data in database.

Now I want to fetch value of particular data value into select2 control when edit the form. My selected select value is store in one variable Now i want that value dispaly in select2 control inside the edit form and i dont know how ..

here is my edit form code:

```
<div id="editm" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Update Rayon</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="validate1" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label">Kode Rayon</label>
        <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_Kode_rayon" name="edit_Kode_rayon" placeholder="Kode Rayon" readonly>
         </div>
        </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Nama Rayon</label>
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_nama_rayon" name="edit_nama_rayon" placeholder="Nama Center" >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Nama Region</label>
            <div>
            <!-- HERE IS THE SELECT2 THAT IM TALKING ABOUT.. -->
              <select class="form-control kode_region" id="nRegionE" name="kode_region" style="width: 100%;">
                <option value=""></option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" id="update" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is jquery code for edit button:

```
$(document).on("click", "#edit", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var editid = $(this).attr("value");
 $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Rayon/editdata",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data:{editid: editid},
      success: function(data){
      if(data.responce == "success"){
         $('#editm').modal('show');
         $("#edit_Kode_rayon").val(data.posts.kode_rayon);
         $("#edit_nama_rayon").val(data.posts.nama_rayon);
         //$("#nRegionE").val(data.posts.kode_region);<-- I TRIED LIKE THIS .. NOT WORK -->
         //$("#nRegionE").select2().select2('val',data.posts.kode_region);<-- I TRIED LIKE THIS . NOT WORK-->
         $('#nRegionE').val(data.posts.kode_region).trigger("change");<-- EVEN THIS ONE IS NOT WORK -->
      }else{
         toastr["error"](data.message);}
      }
      });
      });
```

and here is my Select2 script that im using it for inssert and my edit form:

```
$(function () {$('.kode_region').select2({
 //placeholder: "Please select region",allowClear: true,
 ajax: {
dataType: 'json',
url: '<?=site_url('Bonus/nregion')?>',
type: "post",
delay: 250,
data: function(params) {
  return {search: params.term}},
  processResults: function (data, page) {
    return {results: data};
  },
}
})});
```

just to make it clear i took a screenshot of my edit form:

[image]

all what i want is to fetch the value of data into select2 form control of Edit Form .. can anyone help me to do that ? n i'll be so thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching options list correctly in data.posts.kode_region,
then update this line

```
$("#nRegionE").val(data.posts.kode_region);
```

to this

```
$("#nRegionE").html('<option value = "'+data.posts.kode_region+'" selected >'+data.posts.kode_region+'</option>');
```

and don't forget to comment this line

```
$('#nRegionE').val(data.posts.kode_region).trigger("change");
```

Comment: i did what u ask me to do . $("#nRegionE").html(data.posts.kode_region);
but it doesn't work for me .. do u think that i have to make another script of select2 for edit form ? because the select2 script now is for insert and edit form . both of it had select2 option .. I'M REALLY SORRY BEING LATE TO BE ONLINE AGAIN N TRY UR SOLUTION MY DEAR . and thanks for ur reply

Comment: try to console.log(data) and print the data to me what you are getting there and what I think is you need to parse json data first to get all data working

Comment: here i console.log(data) : `{"responce":"success","posts":{"kode_rayon":"RAYONBDG       ","nama_rayon":"Rayon Bandung                                     ","kode_region":"REGIONJABAR    "}}` .....
and here i console.log(data.posts) :
`{kode_rayon: "RAYONBDG       ", nama_rayon: "Rayon Bandung                                     ", kode_region: "REGIONJABAR    "}
` ..

Comment: you need to parse json data first 
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
I edited my answer also

Comment: i did as u said but i faced new error it says : `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at Function.parse`... should i use Json.stringfy..?

Comment: i just try like this `var data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));`
the error is gone but nothing change the value still not displaying..

Comment: see the updated answer, need to replace the dropdown value with html option tag and no need to parseJson data because you are getting values already there

Comment: thank you soo much Finally its work perfectly brother..
I just wanna ask u .. is it ok if I use `html('<option value = "'+data.posts.kode_region+'">'+data.posts.kode_region+'</option>')` rather than `html('<option value = "'+data.posts.kode_region+'" selected >'+data.posts.kode_region+'</selected>')` .. I just delete `SELECTED` word and `</SELECT>` and replaced the `</SELECT>` to 
 with `</option>`.. 

I'm just curious .. and thank you again for sticking with me and help me solve it brother :)

Comment: Yes this is the correct one, actually it was copy paste issue </selected> but it will be </option>, I corrected my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

I am dam sure this will work for you

```
$("select#nRegionE option").val("hello"); //Change hello string to your record Id
$("select#nRegionE option").html(data.posts.kode_region);
```

Comment: do u mean like this : 
$("select#nRegionE option").val(data.posts.kode_region);
$("select#nRegionE option").html(data.posts.kode_region);
if that what u mean it still nothing changed brother :( ..